# Anyway to detect if a threaded method has completed

Tags: c#, multithreading, blocking

I've got a queue, which is basically the producer/consumer queue in the albahari.com 
threading book, which takes an queue item off the queue, which is an action execution block off the queue and then calls a method to execute the actionlist within the queue item.

I can kill the queue easily enough by enqueing a null actionblock and block the main thread by doing a spin/wait with a thread.sleep() until the queue count goes to zero, and all the threads fall through the while !=null loop, thereby completing, but the method executing the last actionlist may still be executing the last thread.

Question is, is their anyway to detect if that method still has a thread executing it, like maybe using a Semaphore or counter with an Interlock to count the semaphore up at the beginning of the method and count it down at the end. So if it reaches zero, them I know its not threaded.

This is the implementing a destroy method on the interface, to close it down before calling dispose.

Comment: It was the System.Threading.Thread model I was using, and the IsAlive property is ideal for testing, and it works. Thanks for the quick response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you start a thread like this:

```
System.Threading.Thread mythread = new System.Threading.Thread();
mythread.Start();
```

You can check:

```
mythread.IsAlive()
```

at any point to determine its status.

Comment: Polling for the status has been deprecated a long, long time ago, use events.

Answer (score 2):

Use the Backgroundworker which has a completed event

Answer (score 0):

Use a PostSharp attribute on the method.